# C++ default constructor for primitives?

Tags: c++, c++11

So it's my understanding that if I have `SomeType foo`, the default constructor for `SomeType` will be invoked and `foo` will be initialized. But if I have `int x` -- this is undefined according to the spec. Why isn't the default constructor (`int()`) invoked?

Comment: Because `int` isn't a class. Non-class types don't have constructors.

Comment: Also, just because you have a class (e.g. `SomeType` from your example) doesn't mean that its default constructor will actually do something useful. The constructor could leave member variables uninitialized.

Comment: Classes with an implictly-generated default constructor, or `=default`ed in class body, behave in the same way. Doing `MyClass x;` can leave some members uninitialized, and `MyClass()` set to zero the members that otherwise would be uninitialized.

Answer (score 4):

> Why isn't the default constructor (`int()` ) invoked?

The language did not want to impose the cost of calling the constructor and intializing such objects if the programmer wanted them to be left uninitialized.

A clarification:

```
int x;
```

does not cause undefined behavior. Using `x` without initializing it or setting the value explicitly is cause for undefined bahavior.

#### One example

That allows a programmer to allocate large chunks of memory as buffer that can be used later to intialize objects using placement `new`.

```
char* buffer = new char[SOME_LARGE_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

and later

```
// Construct an object in dynamically allocated memory, buffer.
SomeObject* obj = new (buffer+offset) SomeObject;
```

Given the usage of `buffer`, initializing every element of `buffer` is of no value to the user. The cost of initializing such objects is unnecessary imposition given the use case.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is actually right. In hindsight `int x;` being uninitialized (and also `SomeType foo;` can leave some members uninitialized) is a constant source of bugs and security bugs. The rational was, as [R Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61469425/2805305) pointed out to "not pay for what you don't need" which is a core philosophy of C++. Now it might seem laughable that initializing a local `int` variable could be the source of performance concern, especially with today optimizers, but in the old days it was.

Today there is still a need to have variables uninitialized after they are defined (think for instance of arrays that you need to fill afterwards). But the way it's handled in C++ is unfortunate (in hindsight).

A better option would have been to not allow uninitialized variables unless the programmer explicitly asks for it, e.g.:

```
int x = unitialized; // where uninitialized is a keyword
```

... again, in hindsight.

---

Today almost all guidelines recommend to always initialize your variables and to do that you can employ some tricks:

- always use `{}` to initialize your variables, e.g. `int x{};`
- (almost) always use auto which forces you to have initializations, e.g. `auto x = int{};`

Comment: I am interested if there is an opinion against of what I wrote. Please leave a comment.